# What is a Windows command-line EXE's "side-by-side configuration" and how do I correct it?

Tags: windows, configuration, side-by-side, dll

I have a simple .exe written in C++ (built with Visual Studio 2005) that tests some hardware using a supplied API.  It works fine on the Windows 7 machine I built it on, but when I copy it to another (Windows 7) machine and run it (from the command-line) I get:

> The application has failed to start
>   because its side-by-side configuration
>   is incorrect. Please see the
>   application event log or use the
>   command-line sxstrace.exe tool for
>   more detail.

What is "side-by-side configuration"?

I ran sxstrace.exe and read the usage info.  It appears I would need to instrument my exe to generate a log file for sxstrace.exe to be useful?

I imagine the problem is my exe requires DLLs that either don't exist on the other machine, or are the wrong version.  How do I find out what DLLs my exe uses, and what versions it links to on my machine (where it works)?  Any other advice on copying it to another machine and getting it running?  Would more information help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mfawzymkh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116346/mfawzymkh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985277/application-has-failed-to-start-because-the-side-by-side-configauration-is-incorr/985306#985306) to the "[application has failed to start because the side by side configauration is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985277/application-has-failed-to-start-because-the-side-by-side-configauration-is-incorr)" question (linked to in the question [spirulence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307929/spirulence) linked to in his answer to this question) appears to apply to this question also.  mfawzymkh writes:

> You can resolve this issue by either
>   one of these 1- Install VC8 Debug CRT
>   2- Build you app as statically linked

And mfawzymkh's comment on that same answer explains how to build as statically linked:

> when you build it in VS, go to
>   projects->settings->C/C++->Code
>   Generation and choose Runtime Lib
>   options to be /MTd instead of /MDd

I did that and the side-by-side configuration message is gone.  (And after installing something else for the DLL I was using, my EXE works.)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I encountered the same issue. In the Event Viewer I had an error message that read:

Activation context generation failed for "C:\\MyExe.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\\MyExe.exe.Config" on line 12. Invalid Xml syntax.

Sure enough, I'd changed a connection string and left out the closing quote. Added that back in and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

"when you build it in VS, go to projects->settings->C/C++->Code Generation and choose Runtime Lib options to be /MTd instead of /MDd" worked for me, although I was interested in the Release version instead of the Debug version.

Microsofto says:
/MT Causes your application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library. Defines _MT and causes the compiler to place the library name LIBCMT.lib into the .obj file so that the linker will use LIBCMT.lib to resolve external symbols.

/MD
Causes your application to use the multithread- and DLL-specific version of the run-time library. Defines _MT and _DLL and causes the compiler to place the library name MSVCRT.lib into the .obj file.
Applications compiled with this option are statically linked to MSVCRT.lib. This library provides a layer of code that allows the linker to resolve external references. The actual working code is contained in MSVCR100.DLL, which must be available at run time to applications linked with MSVCRT.lib.

Answer (score 1):

Are you suffering from the same issue as this guy? [Side-by-side assemblies, Windows 7, and Visual Studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372604/side-by-side-assemblies-windows-7-and-visual-studio-2005)

Comment: Actually at first glance, it looks like the top answer to this question (linked to from the question you linked to) will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985277/